# Making Wordpress installation able to handle thousands of daily visitors

Tags: php, wordpress, cdn, vps, buddypress

I am currently working on a very specific project using Wordpress and BuddyPress. Plugins:

1. Cubepoints
2. Wordfence. (Was using Better WP Security but had several conflicts)
3. SEO Yoast (The most voted)
4. WPMUDEV Ultimate Facebook, Buddypress Activity Plus.
5. The Youtube RSS pull from Yougapi (Codecanyon)
6. Cometchat professional.
7. Questions and Answers called Sabai.
8. Will add WP Courseware.

And some other plugins that are necessary, like Akismet, Vaultpress, etc. I've bought a theme called Powermag that supports Buddypress.

Problems:

```
Account:      myaccount
Resource:     Virtual Memory Size
Exceeded:     107 > 100 (MB)
Executable:   /usr/bin/php
Command Line: /usr/bin/php /home/myaccount/public_html/index.php
PID:          12188 (Parent PID:9785)
Killed:       No
```

I'm not sure what I have to do, I just need to finish the site so I can add a CDN like CloudFlare, MaxCDN, Cloudfront, etc. I don't know how big portals using Wordpress and all this plugins do to handle this excessive process from PHP.

I would like to know some tips to handle this traffic and make my VPS better for this.
My VPS resources are the following:

```
2536MB   Guaranteed RAM
100GB    RAID-10 Disk Space
4x Priority  8+ CPUs
6500GB   Premium Bandwidth
```

And  here is more info:

```
-bash-3.2# free -m
total used free shared buffers cached
Mem: 2536 846 1689 0 0 0
-/+ buffers/cache: 846 1689
Swap: 0 0 0

Memory Usage:
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs 80G 24G 57G 29% /
/dev/simfs 80G 24G 57G 29% /tmp
none 1.0G 4.0K 1.0G 1% /dev

Disk Usage:
-bash-3.2# df -h
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs 100G 92G 8.8G 92% /
/dev/simfs 100G 92G 8.8G 92% /tmp
none 1.3G 4.0K 1.3G 1% /dev
```

Sorry for the big question. I really need help since I'm not sure what I have to do to deal with big traffic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are exceeding your PHP memory allocation, then your first task is to increase that setting in your `php.ini` so that the site works. However, 107M is quite a lot for a PHP application, so I would next do some profiling to see what is requesting excessive memory. If you have a lot of comments on a post, that can really eat away at it (I once saw a theme that loaded thousands in one go, adding an extra 40-50M to the total process requirement).

Also, consider reducing the number of plugins you have. Do you absolutely need all the plugins you've listed? There may be alternatives that take up less memory, so if you find one that hogs RAM, swap it for something else if you can.

It is important not to optimise until you really need to do so. What are your current traffic levels? If you have *just* thousands of daily visitors, you should be able to handle 12 or so concurrent requests (assuming 120M processes and a chunk for your OS). If each process takes half a second, then that's still a lot of capacity given your 2.5G RAM!

Look into PHP accelerators too, and/or FastCGI - there's a lot of information on the web about that.

Comment: So mainly I will manually upgrade by +40-50MB on the php.ini.
I was trying to install the Google PageSpeed mod for Apache and Nginx. Will that help also?
I was googleing for PHP accelerators, I found eAccelerator. Do you recommend it?

Comment: @DigitalBrain: I think eAccelerator is no longer developed - go with either APC or Zend Opcache. If you can upgrade to PHP 5.5 you'll get the second one bundled without having to install anything, afaik. 140M is probably excessive, try 115M to start with, and increase it if required.

Comment: I got a response from Knownhost about this. Here it is what they told me:
If your question is about increasing PHP memory limit, then no. Thats not the solution. Enabling Cloudflare should reduce number of PHP execution in the server and that way it should reduce the PHP memory usage. But if you are still getting PHP memory error even after enabling CloudFlare then you should consider optimizing your web application by removing unnecessary plugins, code etc. More than 100MB of memory usage per execution from a web app is not normal. 

What do you think?

Comment: I think that's right, since that's pretty much what I said. The only difference I'd make is that I am not convinced you need Cloudflare yet - once you have a half a million hits a day, maybe. As I said yesterday, I suspect you're optimising too early - decide first if you actually need to.